# double free detected in tcache 2 when initializing a list, crashes upon entry insertion

Tags: c++

Reading from a file, each line is stored in a list as an individual row. Each row contains two standard values and a variable amount stored in a list. Therefore each node has two values and a list. Initialization through operator>> works, but as soon as I try to run the `loadfile` function it crashes with the error: `free(): double free detected in tcache 2 Aborted (core dumped)`

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Resource.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "node.h"

using std::cout;
using rows = List<Resource>;
using row = Node<Resource>;

void loadFile(string idata, rows &res)
{
    ifstream ifs(idata, ifstream::in);
    while (ifs.good())
    {
        Resource s;
        ifs >> s;
        row *temp = new Node<Resource>(s);
        res.insert(temp);
    }
    ifs.close();
}

int main()
{
    rows resList;
    loadFile("data.txt", resList);
    cout << resList.getHead()->getValue();
}
```

this is the source for the class that stores the values, that will be wrapped in a Node template class.

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_H
#define RESOURCE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "list.h"
#include "node.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::istream;
using std::string;

class Resource
{
private:
    string Name;
    int amt;
    List<string> clientList;

public:
    Resource(string n, int a) : Name(n), amt(a) {}
    Resource(string n) : Resource(n, 0) {}
    Resource() : Resource("", 0) {}

    string getName()
    {
        return this->Name;
    }
    int getAmt()
    {
        return this->amt;
    }
    void setName(string n)
    {
        this->Name = n;
    }
    void setAmt(int a)
    {
        this->amt = a;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Resource &r)
    {
        out << r.Name << ";" << r.amt;
        List<string> temp = r.clientList;
        for (Node<string> *app = temp.getHead(); app != NULL; app = app->getNext())
        {
            out << ';';
            out << app->getValue();
        }
        return out;
    }
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Resource &r)
    {
        string Name;
        string amt;
        string params;
        string tempVar;
        getline(in, Name, ';');
        getline(in, amt, ';');
        getline(in, params, '\n');
        const int paramsOriginalLength = count(params.begin(), params.end(), ';');
        for (int i = 0; i < paramsOriginalLength; i++)
        {
            r.clientList.insert(params.substr(0, params.find(';')));
            params.erase(0, params.find(';') + 1);
        }
        r.setName(Name);
        r.setAmt(stoi(amt));
        return in;
    }
};

#endif
```

EDIT: Since the problem might be caused by the data structure's defintion I will include the source of list.h and node.h

List:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

// Standard Template Linked List - List - by Eduardo Meli - 2020

#include "node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class List
{
private:
    int length;
    Node<T> *head;

public:
    List(int length, Node<T> *head) : length(length), head(head) {}
    List() : List(0, NULL) {}

    Node<T> *getHead()
    {
        return this->head;
    }

    int getLength()
    {
        return this->length;
    }

    void insert(T value)
    {
        Node<T> *app = new Node<T>(value);
        this->insert(app);
    }

    void insert(Node<T> *n)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            length++;
            return;
        }
        Node<T> *curr = head;
        while (curr->getNext() != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->getNext();
        }
        curr->setNext(n);
        length++;
    }

    void deleteNode(Node<T> *n)
    {
        if (n == this->getHead())
        {
            this->head = head->getNext();
            this->length = length - 1;
            delete n;
            return;
        }
        Node<T> *prev = head;
        Node<T> *curr = head->getNext();
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            if (curr == n)
            {
                prev->setNext(curr->getNext());
                length--;
                return;
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->getNext();
        }
    }

    Node<T> *deleteNode(T value)
    {
        if (this->seekNode(value))
        {
            if (head->getValue() == value)
            {
                Node<T> *temp = head;
                head = head->getNext();
                length--;
                return temp;
            }
            Node<T> *prev = head;
            Node<T> *curr = head->getNext();
            while (curr != NULL)
            {
                if (curr->getValue() == value)
                {
                    prev->setNext(curr->getNext());
                    length--;
                    return curr;
                }
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->getNext();
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    void print()
    {
        Node<T> *nk = this->getHead();
        while (nk != NULL)
        {
            cout << nk->getValue() << endl;
            nk = nk->getNext();
        }
    }

    ~List()
    {
        Node<T> *ptr;

        for (ptr = head; head; ptr = head)
        {
            head = head->getNext();
            delete ptr;
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

And node:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

// Standard Template Linked List - Node - by Eduardo Meli - 2020


#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node
{
private:
    T value;
    Node<T> *next;

public:
    Node(T value, Node<T> *next) : value(value), next(next) {}
    Node(T value) : Node(value, NULL) {}
    Node() : Node(0, NULL) {}
    T getValue()
    {
        return this->value;
    }
    Node<T> *getNext()
    {
        return this->next;
    }
    void setValue(T val)
    {
        this->value = val;
    }
    void setNext(Node<T> *n)
    {
        this->next = n;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Node &n)
    {
        out << n.value;
        return out;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: What is list.h and node.h?

Comment: They are my libraries that basically function as a linked list. I will add them to my question for sake of completeness.

Comment: If you load the core dump in gcc it will tell you exactly where the problem is

Comment: @Taekahn where can I find the dump? I thought it would be in /var/crash but it's empty. And yes I made sure to check ulimit -c.

Comment: @EduardoMeli varies by arch. I would check the directory of the program as well. There is a command to check the directory but o don’t know it offhand.

Comment: I think your problem lives around the lack of copy constructors in the Resource and List classes but with such a lot of code it is difficult to see. Use the core dump as @Taekahn suggests or a debugger and step through your code noting addresses of objects, especially during destructors. I would also define destructors even if it was only to debug what is going on. Also try to reduce the amount of code you are looking at. Remove the List member from Resource, just try to create one and destroy it, does it work, and build up from there. It will help to debug and understand what is happening.

Comment: I predict that the following simple example will reproduce the problem: `List<int> a; a.insert(42); List<int> b = a;` After the copy, `b.head == a.head`; both objects store the same pointer, both think they own it, and both will try to destroy the same node in their respective destructors.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am refactoring the entire class. I am implementing copy constructors, deconstructors, using smart pointers instead of raw ones and wrapping values in Optional<T> (borrowed name from the Java class) and that should be enough to handle every aspect. Still, I need to do more testing.